# End of statement expected - ASP.net in SQL statement

Tags: asp.net, sql, syntax

I am attempting to pass a text box value into a SQL query, something which just does not want to work for me. The error I receive is 'End of statement expected.'

I presume it is a syntax error on my behalf, I am brand new to ASP and would be grateful if someone could point out where I am going wrong. Below is the code that is causing the problem:

```
queryCourse = "INSERT INTO users ( [name] ) VALUES ('" + queryCourse += textbox1.text + "');"
```

I am able to insert hard coded value into the database using this statement so I know that my database connection is not a problem, therefore I presume it is a problem with possibly the concatenation or the way I am referring to the text box.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is extremely bad programming practice.  You should pass the data into a query or stored procedure as a parameter.  Also you need to validate the input that is being passed in.

Comment: This is the portion of code taken from the tutorial that I was following, I cannot post the full tutorial as it is on a university student area requiring a login.

queryCourse = "INSERT INTO course (idcourse, modnum, modname) VALUES ("queryCourse += textbox1.text + ",'"queryCourse += textbox2.text + "','"queryCourse += textbox3.text + "');"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the code `queryCourse += textbox1.text`, remove the "queryCourse +=" part and then try it. Unless you actually want to concatenate queryCourse and textbox1.text, in which case remove the "=" (which I suspect you don't, given that you're setting queryCourse to be the SQL you wish to execute).

In other words, your code should read:

```
queryCourse = "INSERT INTO users ( [name] ) VALUES ('" + textbox1.text + "');"
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for the quick reply. I guess the tutorial I am following is wrong? Cheers again, sorted.

Answer (score 3):

```
queryCourse = "INSERT INTO users ( [name] ) VALUES ('" + textbox1.text + "');"
```

But be aware that this allows unfiltered values to be passed and so [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is possible..

Answer (score 1):

```
queryCourse = "INSERT INTO users ( [name] ) VALUES ('" + textbox1.text + "');"
```